# Wildcard query over _all field on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform wildcard queries over the _all field. An example query could be:

```
GET index/type/_search
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 1000,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "wildcard" : {
          "_all" : "*tito*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that to use a wildcard query the _all field needs to be not_analyzed, otherwise the query won't work. See [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) for more info.

I tried to set the [mappings over the _all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field) using this request:

```
PUT index
{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "_all" : {
              "enabled" : true,
              "index_analyzer": "not_analyzed",
              "search_analyzer": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "_timestamp": {
                "enabled": "true"
            },
            "properties": {
                "someProp": {
                  "type": "date"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error **analyzer [not_analyzed] not found for field [_all]**.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong and if there is another (better) way to perform this kind of queries.

Thanks.-

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing:

```
"search_analyzer": "not_analyzed"
```

Also, I wonder how well a wildcard across all properties will scale. Have you looked into NGrams? See the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html).

Comment: I've tried NGrams and works much better. The problem with NGrams is that consume a lot of disk space. Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: Yes, NGrams do take a lot of disk space (and more CPU).  You can experiment with min_gram and max_gram settings. Given the way the ngrams are stored,setting too low or too high will eat disk space. In some cases using [edgeNGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) may consume less resources, but anchors the ngram to the start of the token.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you wanted to give option 
   `"index": "not_analyzed"`
Index attribute for a string field, _all is a string field, determines if that field should be analyzed or not.

`"search_analyzer"` is to set to determine which analyzer should be used for user entered query, which is valid if index attribute is set to analyzed.
`"index_analyzer"` is to set to determine which analyzer should be used for documents, again which is valid if index attribute is set to analyzed.